# How to generate cucumber html report with attached failed screenshot and cucumber.json file using gradle based project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Using gradle, I am trying generate cucumber html report with failed screenshot attached to it for security reason I cannot have online plugins in **build.gradle** file so I have to download required jar and plugins and implement and configure library manually in **build.gradle** file.

Please suggest how can configure TestRunner file in build.gradle and generate cucumber html report with cucumber.json file

**build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


configurations {
    cucumberRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'stepDef', 'src/test/java']
        }
    }
}



repositories {

    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir:System.getProperty("user.dir")+'/Plugin',include:['*.jar'])
    implementation files('junit-4.12')
    implementation files('testng-6.7.jar')
    implementation files('junit-jupiter-api-5.6.2')
    implementation files('hamcrest-all-1.3')
    .....................
```

**TestRunner file**

```
package TestRunner;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources",
        glue = "StepDefs",
        plugin = {
                "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber.json", "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt"
        }
)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: Rename `target/cucumber-html-report` to `target/cucumber-html-report.html`.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Environment\openjdk-13+33_windows-x64_bin\jdk-13\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje if i am running simple feature file execution is happening but no reports is generated but if i am running this gradle task it throws the above error

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `StepDefs` may be ...

Running with `gradle cucumber --info` might be useful for debugging... because the error message `finished with non-zero exit value 1` just indicates "error" or "no success".

You'd probably need these Java dependencies, to begin with:

```
testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.5.0'
testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.5.0'
```

And one might have to add `gradle.cucumber` as the `--glue` into the arguments `args`, as the [documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/tools/java/#gradle) suggests. Task dependency `compileTestJava` should rather be `testClasses`.

`html` generally is a plugin, which expects an output directory, therefore this should look alike this:

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, testClasses
    doFirst {

    }
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = 'io.cucumber.core.cli.Main'
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = [
                '--plugin', 'pretty', 'html:target/reports',
                '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber',
                'src/test/resources'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

These `args` can also be annotated in Java; not sure which of them takes precedence.
It probably makes no sense and only creates a mess, when defining the arguments twice.

Make sure to follow instruction #4:

> Add feature `.feature` files and associated step mapping classes `.java` in `src/test/resources` and `src/test/java` respectively in a `gradle.cucumber` package.

> `-g`, `--glue` **PATH** Where glue code (step definitions, hooks and plugins) are loaded from.

When running with jUnit, one can also pass options with a `junit-platform.properties` file.

---

The most easy might be to start with the [`cucumber-java-skeleton`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) (it is known to be working).

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me, If I run this cucumber task it gives me error

Task :cucumber FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class io.cucumber.api.cli.Main

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.api.cli.Main

**Error: Could not find or load main class io.cucumber.api.cli.Main**

I have created one task cucumberRunner which executes the TestRunner.java file, it is creating cucumber.json file and html report but htlm
report but HTML report is not expected is weird no graphics and colorless colorless

**build.gradle I'm using:**

````
```
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, testClasses
    doFirst {

    }
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = 'io.cucumber.api.cli.Main'     // tried with  io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = [
                    '--plugin', 'pretty', 'html:target/reports',
                    '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber',
                    'src/test/resources'
            ]
        }
    }
}
task cucumberRunner(type: Test) {
    include '**/**TestRunner.class'
}
````

````
       Also I have added jars
           implementation files('junit-4.12')
           implementation files('testng-6.0.jar')
           implementation files('cucumber-core-6.0.0')
           implementation files('cucumber-java-6.0.0')
           implementation files('cucumber-plugin-6.0.0')
           implementation files('cucumber-junit-6.0.0')
           implementation files('cucumber-testng-6.0.0')
           implementation files('cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5')
           implementation files('cucumber-gherkin-6.0.0')
           implementation files('cucumber-java8-6.0.0')
           implementation files('cucumber-html-0.2.3')
       ```
````